# Is there any api for interrupt scala shell programmatically

Tags: scala

I know that ctrl+c can interrupt scala shell, but I will wrap scala shell in my application and want to interrupt it programmatically, is there any api for that ? thanks

Comment: Do you mean interrupt while it is running user code? Not really. You can wrap user code in arbitrary code, to check a flag and quit.

Comment: No, I wrap scala shell to my app, and I want to interrupt the scala shell via api in my app.

Answer (score 1):

There is a command `:quit` which can be invoked onto shell to get a normal exit.